# Is there any plugin that show the train route in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am currently working on Qgis for a project, and I want to map the route between two stadiums. I managed to create a route for the bus using the orstools plugin, but i can't manage to create a route for the train or plane. Is there any plugin that allows me to?

Comment: [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this question.

Comment: It is highly suggested to ask QGIS-related questions on [the Geographic Information Systems SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)